# How to pass dynamic folder name for HTML reports in @CucumberOptions

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Currenlty, Im passing path of HTML report generation via CucumberOptions in Runner class. however with each run the old report gets overwritten. is there a way to pass new folder name with each run or inbuilt cucumber option to generate new folder name for each run?

here is my code:

> `@CucumberOptions( features = "src/test/resources/features",
>   glue="com.bnymellon.sse.ui.step_definitions", tags = {"@demo"},
>   monochrome = true, plugin = {"html:output/HTML_Reports/"} )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [three way](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton)s to override Cucumber Options.

1. cucumber.options="..." passed to the JVM with -Dcucumber.options="...".
2. The environment variable CUCUMBER_OPTIONS="...".
3. A cucumber-jvm.properties on the CLASSPATH with a cucumber.options="..." property.

There is a caveat; you cannot override, but only add a plugin.  So you would need to remove the html plugin from your @CucumberOptions and specify the html plugin using one of the 3 methods listed above.

If you just want to avoid having to edit your runner class for each run then I would move the html plugin to:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:output/HTML_Reports"
```

on your runner's VM arguments box.  You can then edit VM arguments before each run which avoids triggering git.  I often override the tags argument this way.